# How can I simplify repeating function logic

Tags: rust, refactoring, program-structure

## Question

I'm wondering if there is a way to improve the current structure of some functions in my program since I feel there is a fair amount of unwanted repetition happening.

### Background

I'm writing a tiny logger so CLI applications can have prettier text in the terminal. I have a couple functions that add some icons to what is going to stdout such as `success()`, it takes a message and adds a green checkmark icon to it, same with `error()`, `warn()` etc. They can all either add a newline character at the end or ignore it depending on if the user called `same()` before it.

Currently they use the three functions defined below to decide whether or not to add a newline, and whether or not to add a timestamp.

### Code

```rust
/// Outputs to stdout with an icon
fn output<T: Display>(&mut self, message: T, icon: LogIcon) {
    let timestamp = self.timestamp();

    if self.same_line {
        print!("{} {}{}", icon, timestamp, message);
    } else {
        println!("{} {}{}", icon, timestamp, message);
    }

    self.same_line = false;
}

/// Outputs to stderr with an icon
fn output_error<T: Display>(&mut self, message: T, icon: LogIcon) {
    let timestamp = self.timestamp();

    if self.same_line {
        eprint!("{} {}{}", icon, timestamp, message);
    } else {
        eprintln!("{} {}{}", icon, timestamp, message);
    }

    self.same_line = false;
}

/// Outputs to stdout normally
fn output_normal<T: Display>(&mut self, message: T) {
    let timestamp = self.timestamp();

    if self.same_line {
        print!("{}{}", timestamp, message);
    } else {
        println!("{}{}", timestamp, message);
    }

    self.same_line = false;
}
```

This is how the `success` function makes use of output function at the moment:

```rust
pub fn success<T: Display>(&mut self, message: T) {
    self.output(message, LogIcon::CheckMark);   
}
```

The same applies for all other functions, they either output to `stderr` or `stdout`.

Answer (score 2):

You could change `same_line` into `line_ending`. Instead of storing true, you would store `\n` and always use `print!("... {}", ..., &self.line_ending)`. I would also add a function `pop_line_ending()` which returns the stored line ending and clears it.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a function that is generic over implementations of `std::io::Writer`, and also accepts `std::fmt::Arguments`, which is the formatting arguments applied at compile time to the input string in a way that can be conveniently passed around.

```
use std::{fmt, fmt::Display, io};

fn write_output<W: io::Write>(&mut self, args: fmt::Arguments, newline: bool, mut writer: W) {
    write!(writer, "{}", args).unwrap();
    if newline {
        write!(writer, "\n").unwrap();
    }
    writer.flush().unwrap();
}
```

Then pass either `stdout()` or `stderr()` as required in each call, along with the other arguments:

```
fn output<T: Display>(&mut self, message: T, icon: LogIcon) {
    let timestamp = self.timestamp();
    self.write_output(
        format_args!("{} {}{}", icon, timestamp, message),
        !self.same_line,
        io::stdout(),
    );
    self.same_line = false;
}

fn output_error<T: Display>(&mut self, message: T, icon: LogIcon) {
    let timestamp = self.timestamp();
    self.write_output(
        format_args!("{} {}{}", icon, timestamp, message),
        !self.same_line,
        io::stderr(),
    );
    self.same_line = false;
}

fn output_normal<T: Display>(&mut self, message: T) {
    let timestamp = self.timestamp();
    self.write_output(
        format_args!("{}{}", timestamp, message),
        !self.same_line,
        io::stdout(),
    );
    self.same_line = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Peter Hall's solution, but I think it can be simplified. I got rid of the `fmt::Arguments` argument and passed in the message and optional icon. Also got rid of the `newline` argument and used the member variable directly.

```
use std::{fmt, fmt::Display, io};

struct LogIcon {}

impl Display for LogIcon {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
        write!(f, "[ICON]")
    }
}

struct Logger {
    same_line: bool,
}

impl Logger {
    fn write_output<T: Display, W: io::Write>(
        &mut self,
        message: T,
        icon: Option<LogIcon>,
        mut writer: W,
    ) {
        if let Some(icon) = icon {
            write!(writer, "{} ", icon);
        }
        write!(writer, "{}{}", self.timestamp(), message);

        if self.same_line {
            write!(writer, "\n").unwrap();
        }
        writer.flush().unwrap();
        self.same_line = false;
    }

    fn output<T: Display>(&mut self, message: T, icon: LogIcon) {
        self.write_output(message, Some(icon), io::stdout());
    }

    fn output_error<T: Display>(&mut self, message: T, icon: LogIcon) {
        self.write_output(message, Some(icon), io::stderr());
    }

    fn output_normal<T: Display>(&mut self, message: T) {
        self.write_output(message, None, io::stdout())
    }

    fn timestamp(&self) -> &'static str {
        "A TIMESTAMP"
    }
}
```